# Raspberry pi 4, Tensorflow , open cv

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, import, raspberry-pi

I successfully installed TensorFlow and OpenCV on Raspberry Pi 4.
But, I can only import TensorFlow on python 3, but not on python 2. Conversely, I can only import cv2 on python2 but not on python 3.
I would like to know how to import both, either on pyhton2 or on python3.

[image]

Comment: You should be able to import opencv2 with python3 if you installed if correctly. How did you install opencv2? From the images I guess you didn't use virtual environments? This is highly recommended to not pollute your original env. However if you want to process, try install it via `python3 -m pip install opencv-python` which will install it based on your python3

Answer (score 0):

I suggest one thing python 2 will be obsolete from January 2020, So better create a virtual environment and install the Opencv and tensorflow. Please follow this instruction provided on the link to install opencv : https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/26/install-opencv-4-on-your-raspberry-pi/